# cron job - Run at different time on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday

Tags: linux, cron

I want my cron run the script on Monday at 10, Wednesday at 11 and at Friday at 12

I tried this

```
0 10 * * 1,3,5
```

But this will run the script 10h those days, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate task for different days with different time:

```
 0 10 * * 1 command to be executed
 0 11 * * 3 command to be executed
 0 12 * * 5 command to be executed
```